# Tense in Indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

which option will sit right with the sentence.I can't come to a right option; I'm confused.Please do explain your choice.

> She told me that she had a good job with a big salary, but she ______.
>   a) doesn't
>   b) didn't 
>   c) hadn't
>   d) wasn't

Comment: How about a trade? We'll explain our choice if you explain your confusion :D. I'm betting your answer is probably not too far off from the mark.

Comment: I think your sentence is incomplete. It can be anything but she wasn't

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right: it's a bad question, and the answer can be either doesn't or didn't. Hadn't is just about possible, but it is not natural.

In a sentence like this, there is some [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))- the removal of duplicated text from the second clause of a sentence. Let's put it back and see what we get.

> She told me that she had a good job with a big salary, but she doesn't [have a good job].

This means that she told you, probably recently, that she has a good job but right now she does not have a good job.

> She told me that she had a good job with a big salary, but she didn't [have a good job].

This means that she told you, at some unspecified time in the past, that she has a good job but at that time she did not have a good job. This is probably the form that most people would use.

> She told me that she had a good job with a big salary, but she hadn't [ a good job].

This would definitely be an option in some regional dialects, for example Scottish, but in standard British or American English, when we negate a main verb, we normally add the auxiliary verb **do** and negate that instead, so **had a good job** is negated to **didn't have a good job**.

Negating **hadn't** as a main verb is possible but uncommon, however it is always used in some idioms, for example "she hadn't a clue" or "she hadn't a chance".

Note that if **had** were an auxiliary verb, not a main one, you would simply negate it without adding a further auxiliary verb. For example, in this sentence, **seen** is the main verb and **had** is an auxiliary verb:

> She said that she **hadn't** seen him.

Finally, here are some unsuccessful attempts to make a sentence using wasn't.

> She told me that she had a good job with a big salary, but she wasn't [a good job].
>   She told me that she had a good job with a big salary, but she wasn't [have a good job].